# how to config golang plugins in pycharm?

Tags: macos, go, pycharm

I want to develop Go use pycharm. My golang version is 1.4.2.And my pycharm version is 4.5.2.My operating system is Mac OSX 10.10.3.I have configured the GOROOT and GOPATH on my Mac.Like the pictures:
[image]

I download the golang plugin from this [url](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5047). But when I installed the plugin and restart pycharm, the IDE show me that no gopath and goroot. The messages:

[image]

what's wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure how you managed to install this version, you shouldn't be able to get it for pycharm 4.5+. Anyway, please follow the response from Andrew C. and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the latest [pre-release build of the new golang IDEA plugin](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin). There's been a lot of work recently on it by two Jetbrains employees and it's gotten much better than the currently released version.

Answer (score 3):

Create environment vairiables `gopath` and `goroot`.

For example,

```
export GOPATH='goHomePath'

export GOROOT='< goRootPath >'
```